# VBA to copy specified random data from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba, random, get

```
Sub getdata()

'CTRL+J

    Windows("sample rnd.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1:L5215").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("rnd sample draft.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Random Sample").Select
    Sheets("Random Sample").Name = "Random Sample"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Above is my code so far. It is just copying data from another another workbook and pasting it to my specified worksheet.

What I want is to get random data (rows) without duplicates and I always want to include the first row since it contains the header.

Also, I want to have a text box where I can input number so that I can specify how many data to get from the other workbook. Quite new to vba. need help.

I attached a screenshot.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to load the rows in an array, shuffle the rows and write the array to the target:

```
Sub CopyRandomRows()
  Dim source As Range, target As Range, randCount&, data(), value, r&, rr&, c&

  ' define the source to take the data
  Set source = Workbooks("CheckSum3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet17").Range("$A$1:$B$10")
  ' define the target to paste the data
  Set target = Workbooks("rnd sample draft.xlsm").Worksheets("Random Sample").Range("A1")
  ' define the number of rows to generate
  randCount = 5

  ' load the data in an array
  data = source.value

  'shuffle the rows
  For r = 1 To randCount
    rr = 1 + Math.Round(VBA.Rnd * (UBound(data) - 1))
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
      value = data(r, c)
      data(r, c) = data(rr, c)
      data(rr, c) = value
    Next
  Next

  ' write the data to the target
  target.Resize(randCount, UBound(data, 2)) = data

End Sub
```

Comment: getting error with this line of code       data(r, c) = data(rr, c)    Also, I can't run the code for the second time, it gives me error even if it runs successfully at the first time

Comment: Thank you! But i have another question. Why is it that it is only getting 2 columns? How can i be able to get all columns? I need to get columns until column L. Also, I want to be able to use the TextBox to define how many random sample to get by inputting number in the textbox so when i click the button, the number of random sample will depend on what i input in the textbox. i hope you can help me out with this

Comment: The number of columns is defined by source which is "$A$1:$B$10" in my example. You can change it to "A1:L5215". The number of samples is defined by randCount which can be changed too with the value of your textbox.

Comment: Anyway, I can just simply manually input the header and paste the random sample starting from the second row to not make things more complicated but i need to exclude the first row in getting sample data because it might be included

Comment: To get the data from an input box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673105/get-the-value-of-a-textbox-to-a-cell

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=vba+assign++textbox+value+to+variable

Comment: Set source = Workbooks("CheckSum3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet17").Range("$A$1:$B$10") how do i make this part of the code as dynamic range? because my data is changing everytime.

Answer (score 1):

a "not so smart" way to do it would be something like this:

```
Sub Macro1(numRows As Long)
  Dim a As Long, i As Long, rng As Range
  Windows("sample rnd.xlsm").Activate
  a = Int(Rnd() * 5213) + 2
  Set rng = Range("A1:L1")

  For i = 1 To numRows
    While Not Intersect(Cells(a, 1), rng) Is Nothing
      a = Int(Rnd() * 5213) + 2
    Wend
    Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A1:L5215").Rows(a))
  Next

  rng.Copy
  Sheets("Random Sample").Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

if you are not going for a huge amount of lines... you also could put all lines in a collection and then delete one random item in it till the count reaches the number of lines you want like this (also not so smart solution):

```
Sub Macro2(numRows As Long)
  Dim a As Long, myCol As New Collection, rng As Range
  Windows("sample rnd.xlsm").Activate

  For a = 2 To 5215
    myCol.Add a
  Next

  While myCol.Count > numRows
    myCol.Remove Int(Rnd() * myCol.Count) + 1
  Wend

  Set rng = Range("A1:L1")
  For a = 1 To myCol.Count
    Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A1:L5215").Rows(myCol(a)))
  Next

  rng.Copy
  Sheets("Random Sample").Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

if you still have questions, just ask ;)

Comment: one question. Why can't i run the code? should i insert it to a module or somewhere? take note that i have a text box that should contain how many data should i get from the other workbook. I haven't done anything yet with the text box.

Comment: you need to call the sub with a value like on button click `Macro1 TextBox1.Value`. you can test this in direct window (just something like `Macro2 12` to get Row 1 and 12 other random lines)

Comment: sorry but i wasn't able to understand. where exactly should i put your code and how do i connect them with mine. Also, i am not familiar with calling subs. I just recorded a macro that copies all data from other workbook and that's all my code does when i click the button where my macro is assigned