# VBA text string limit in Textbox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

I came across an answer on here regarding getting text from a textBox in Excel, using VBA:

[Get the value of a textbox to a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673105/get-the-value-of-a-textbox-to-a-cell)

I commented today but not being sure whether that will be picked up I thought I'd ask the question.

My Excel version is 2002/ version 10. My query is whether this method of returning the text from a `TextBox` is limited to return a certain number of characters / length of string.

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text`

This returns the text but it is not returning the entire string.

When I use:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "blah blah blah"`

It sets the text to "blah blah blah" unless the initial text is quite long.  In which case it overwrites the majority of the existing text "blah blah blah" but then also includes the remaining part of text.

I hope this makes sense and I hope somebody knows the answer.

Thanks

****IN ADDITION****
In fact, I have just looked and what is interesting and think answers my question is the amount of characters it returns is 255 (the famous 255).

So with this in mind I think my question needs changing to, "Is there a way around this being limited to 255 characters?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my 32-bit Excel 2013 the limit is **32767** - (2^15)-1 - characters. Try run this VBA and see if you get the same error has me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim strFill As String
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim lng As Long


    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        ws.Range("A1").Left, ws.Range("A1").Top, 500, 500)
    strTest = "blah blah blah"

    'enter 32767 x characters in textbox
    strFill = VBA.String(32767, "x")
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strFill

    'check the string length
    MsgBox Len(shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text)

    'overwrite the string
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strTest
    MsgBox "overwritten with " & strTest

    'enter 32768 x characters in textbox
    strFill = VBA.String(32768, "x")
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strFill '<~~ error should occur on this line!

End Sub
```

The error is:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Text property of the Characters class

Occuring on the 2nd line of code below, where an attempt is made to populate the `Textbox` which a string of 32,768 characters in length:

```
strFill = VBA.String(32768, "x")
shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strFill
```

Comment: So is it simple to say it is because I am using a very old version of Excel (I believe version 10.0, 2002) this won't work?

Comment: I expect that the limit changes from version to version - I added this pertinent information to your question. HTH for Excel 2013. WHy don't you try running the code with 255 and 256 limits on your version and update your question?

Comment: You're right, the limits are much less.  Thanks for your response, I'm going to have to have a little re-think of what I am doing.